# Interpreting interactions in beta regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, beta-regression

***Edit***
I am using a log link and `log(statemb)` because my specific goal is to be able to conclude for small changes, an 1% increase in `statemb` leads to a beta_i increase in `stateur`.  Therefore the primary coefficient interpretations I am interested in are those involving the main effect of `statemb` and its interactions with control variables.

I am attempting to interpret the coefficients from a beta regression.  Below is a sample beta regression with log link function using R:

stateur: state unemployment rate (numeric)

statemb: state maximum benefit level (numeric)

age: age in years (numeric)

sex: factor with levels (male,female) (categorical)

married: if individual is married (categorical)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(betareg)
library(Ecdat)
data("Benefits", package = "Ecdat")

Benefits=Benefits %>% mutate(stateur=stateur/100)
Call:
betareg(formula = (stateur) ~ (age) + sex + married + (log(statemb) * age) + (log(statemb) * sex) + 
    (log(statemb) * married) + (log(statemb) * sex * married), data = Benefits, link = "log")


Coefficients (mean model with log link):
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -5.622243   0.397495 -14.144  < 2e-16 ***
age                              0.008963   0.008606   1.041    0.298    
sexmale                         -0.020894   0.314155  -0.067    0.947    
marriedyes                       0.133234   0.363398   0.367    0.714    
log(statemb)                    -0.302992   0.077355  -3.917 8.97e-05 ***
age:log(statemb)                -0.001927   0.001673  -1.152    0.249    
sexmale:log(statemb)             0.009721   0.061074   0.159    0.874    
marriedyes:log(statemb)         -0.025369   0.070789  -0.358    0.720    
sexmale:marriedyes              -0.384411   0.422497  -0.910    0.363    
sexmale:marriedyes:log(statemb)  0.075248   0.082167   0.916    0.360    

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)  13473.7      275.2   48.95   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 3.398e+04 on 11 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.07049
Number of iterations: 105 (BFGS) + 15 (Fisher scoring)
```

Interpretation:

I believe these main effects interpretations are correct

`age`- unit increase in age leads to `(exp(.008963)-1)*100` percent change in mean unemployment rate

`sexmale`-  the mean unemployment rate is `exp(-.02)`  times lower versus females

`married`- mean unemployment rate is `exp(0.13323)` higher for married individuals

`log(statemb)` - 1% change in `statemb`  leads to  -0.302992 change in mean unemployment rate

Given the above are correct  how would the interactions be interpreted, below is my understanding

`age:log(statemb)` - Best to plot and summarise relationship

`sexmale:log(statemb)` - a 1% increase in `statemb` leads to a 0.009721 percent increase in the mean unemployment rate relative to females

`marriedyes:log(statemb)`-  a 1% increase in `statemb` leads to a -0.025369 percent increase in the mean unemployment rate relative to unmarried individuals

`sexmale:marriedyes` - married males versus unmarried females?

`sexmale:marriedyes:log(statemb)` -  a 1% increase in statemb leads to a  0.075248 percent increase in the mean unemployment rate for married males relative to unmarried females

Are the interpretations of the interaction coefficients correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to this forum, @statq!  I'll give you some suggestions you can use to make model interpretation easier.

Typically, beta regression is used with a *logit* link, so I will assume the same in my answer. (You are currently using a *log* link.)

With a *logit* link in place, it sounds like your beta regression model is of the following form:

```
logit(mean UR) = beta_0+ 
                 beta_1 x age + 
                 beta_2 x sexmale +  
                 beta_3 x marriedyes +  
                 beta_4 x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_5 x age x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_6 x sexmale x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_7 x marriedyes x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_8 x sexmale x marriedyes + 
                 beta_9 x sexmale x marriedyes x log(statemb)
```

where unemployment rate (UR) is expresses as a proportion.

Now, let's say you want to interpret the effect of sex on the logit-transformed mean unemployment rate, adjusted for the effects of the other predictor variables in your model. To this end, you can re-arrange your model so that all terms involving the dummy variable sexmale (which is used to encode the effect of sex) are grouped together:

```
logit(mean UR) = beta_0 + 
                 beta_1 x age + 
                 [beta_2 + beta_6 x log(statemb) + beta_8 x marriedyes + beta_9 x marriedyes x log(statemb)] x sexmale +  
                 beta_3 x marriedyes + 
                 beta_4 x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_5 x age x log(statemb) + 
                 beta_7 x marriedyes x log(statemb)
```

This model re-arrangement makes it easier to see that the effect of sex in the model depends on both log(statemb) and marriedyes. To tease out what the effect looks like, you could consider breaking it down into manageable pieces. How you break it down will depend on what the distribution of log(statemb) looks like.

Let's say the distribution of log(statemb) is unimodal and (approximately) symmetric . Then you can consider its obseverd mean value (M) as well as M - SD and M + SD as 3 values for which you want to express the effect of sex. (Here, SD is the observed standard deviation of the distribution of log(statemb).) Considering that marriedyes takes two possible values (i.e., 1 for married and 0 for unmarried), this will give you 6 possible scenarios for which you can express the effect of sex at particular values of age:

1. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M and marriedyes = 1;
2. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M and marriedyes = 0;
3. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M - SD and marriedyes = 1;
4. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M - SD and marriedyes = 0;
5. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M + SD and marriedyes = 1;
6. Effect of sex when log(statemb) is equal to M + SD and marriedyes = 0.

For the first of these scenarios, the *estimated* effect of sex on the logit-transformed mean UR is therefore:

```
  b_2 + b_6 x M + b_8  + b_9  x M
```

where the b's are the *estimated* values of the unknown coefficients beta's. Among people having an average value for log(statemb) and the same age, the mean UR of males differs from the mean UR of females by a multiplicative factor of exp(b_2 + b_6 x M + b_8  + b_9  x M).

If you know how to set up and tests linear contrasts of model coefficients in a beta regression model (on the logit scale), you can easily derive a confidence interval to go with the point estimate b_2 + b_6 x M + b_8  + b_9  x M.

Note that *effect plots* are also a great way to visualize the effects I described above.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  Could you review my edits and include any information that would change in your answer given my added information?